# Sharepoint 2013 pptx to png conversion error AsyncResult operation exceeded timeout of 00:05:00

Tags: sharepoint-server

Can anyone please tell the solution for error "`AsyncResult operation exceeded timeout of 00:05:00`"?

I am trying to convert Presentation into png images.

```
// Convert to PNG  
PictureRequest request = new PictureRequest(inStream, ".pptx", PictureFormat.Png, outStream);
IAsyncResult result = request.BeginConvert(SPServiceContext.GetContext(siteCollection), null, null);
request.EndConvert(result);
```

After 5 minutes it gives this error.

As soon as error is encountered, 4 logs are logged into event viewer as follows,

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  Presenter

  - EventID 0

  [ Qualifiers]  0

  Level 2

  Task 0

  Keywords 0x80000000000000

  - TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2014-06-04T13:03:54.000000000Z

  EventRecordID 14112

  Channel Application

  Computer NGD10220

  Security
- EventData

### Error converting 3486398.pptx to PNG images. AsyncResult operation exceeded timeout of 00:05:00

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0

  - EventID 1325

  [ Qualifiers]  49152

  Level 2

  Task 0

  Keywords 0x80000000000000

  - TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2014-06-04T13:03:55.000000000Z

  EventRecordID 14113

  Channel Application

  Computer NGD10220

  Security
- EventData

  An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated. Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT/Services Process ID: 10376

Exception: System.Runtime.CallbackException Message: Async Callback threw an exception. StackTrace: at

System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously) at

System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.CallComplete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception) at

System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishSend(IAsyncResult result, Boolean completedSynchronously) at

System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result) at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean

completedSynchronously) at System.ServiceModel.Security.ApplySecurityAndSendAsyncResult`1.SharedCallback(IAsyncResult result) at

System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result) at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean

completedSynchronously) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnSend

(IAsyncResult result) at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result) at

System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously) at

System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SendAsyncResult.OnWriteStreamedMessage(IAsyncResult result) at

System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result) at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean

completedSynchronously) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WriteStreamedMessageAsyncResult.OnWriteStreamedMessage

(IAsyncResult result) at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result) at

System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously) at System.Runtime.ScheduleActionItemAsyncResult.DoWork(Object

state) at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped*

nativeOverlapped) at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead,

NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped) at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode,

UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) InnerException: System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not set to

an instance of an object. StackTrace: Server stack trace: at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) at

System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result) at

System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result) at

System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeEndService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at

System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at

System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at

Microsoft.Office.Server.PowerPoint.Conversion.IConversionService.EndConvert(IAsyncResult result) at

Microsoft.Office.Server.PowerPoint.Conversion.ConversionServiceProxy.OnResponseReceived(IAsyncResult result) at

System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)

---

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  .NET Runtime

  - EventID 1026

  [ Qualifiers]  0

  Level 2

  Task 0

  Keywords 0x80000000000000

  - TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2014-06-04T13:03:55.000000000Z

  EventRecordID 14114

  Channel Application

  Computer NGD10220

  Security
- EventData

  Application: w3wp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.Runtime.CallbackException Stack: at System.Runtime.Fx+IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32,

UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*) at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32,

System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)

---

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  Application Error

  - EventID 1000

  [ Qualifiers]  0

  Level 2

  Task 100

  Keywords 0x80000000000000

  - TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2014-06-04T13:03:56.000000000Z

  EventRecordID 14115

  Channel Application

  Computer NGD10220

  Security
- EventData

  w3wp.exe 
  8.0.9200.16384 
  50108835 
  KERNELBASE.dll 
  6.2.9200.16864 
  531d34d8 
  e0434352 
  0000000000047b8c 
  2888 
  01cf7ff4a1d87b7e 
  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe 
  C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll 
  aee9f915-ebe8-11e3-9413-c03fd555d5b1

I have a webservice hosted on sharepoint server which is trying to convert Presentation into images exist on sharepoint site using powerpoint automatioin services.

Comment: How large is this presentation? If you take a single slide presentation, do you get the same result?

Comment: It happens with single slide also. I checked the powerpoint Automation services on sharepoint and those are running, PowerPoint Conversion Service Application and PowerPoint Conversion Service Application Proxy. Also PowerPoint Conversion Service is set to Started in Manage services. I think application is not able to communicate with the automation services proxy. That's why it is giving timeout. I am still clueless over the solution.

Comment: I created sample application as described in the following link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179894(v=office.15).aspx But this application also producing same timeout error

Comment: A couple things I would check: Make sure the Service Application Account you're running the Service App under has Farm Administrator rights which is required for PAS. Also, I have a solution at http://pas.codeplex.com. You can take a look at Conversion.cs as an example of using PictureRequest.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is,

1. In IIS, the application pool under which the Powerpoint conversion service application is running specify the identity of administrator user in advanced settings.
2. User should be part of user groups WSS_ADMIN_WPG, WSS_WPG, WSS_RESTRICTED_WPG_V4
3. Add this user to security section of Sharepoint_Config table in sql server

this issue is due to insufficient permissions assigned to the user.